# How can you send multiple variables from Arduino to Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino

So I currently have this for arduino.ino:

```
Serial.println(Variable1);
```

that does this in Unity:

```
string variable1 = stream.ReadLine();
float x = float.Parse(variable1);
transform.Rotate (0, -x/1000, 0);
```

My question is; How would I send 3 variables from the Arduino to Unity so I can put each value into the `transform.Rotate` function at once?

For example in pseudocode:

```
Arduino.ino
send(Variable1, Variable2, Variable3);

Unity
transform.Rotate(Variable1,Variable2,Variable3);
```

I hope this makes sense. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Arduino side you use code such as:

```cpp
void sendVector(float x, float y, float z) {
  Serial.print(x, 4);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(y, 4);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(z, 4);
}
```

Be aware of precision here. For floats `Serial.print(x);` is equivalent to `Serial.print(x, 2);` which gives you two decimal places. `Serial.print(x, 4);` gives you four decimal places. i.e.:

- Serial.print(1.23456) => "1.23"
- Serial.print(1.23456, 2) => "1.23"
- Serial.print(1.23456, 4) => "1.2345"

REF: [Serial.print()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/print)

Now, on the Unity side, you use C# code such as:

```cs
string[] elements = stream.ReadLine().Split(' ');
float x = float.Parse(elements[0]);
float y = float.Parse(elements[1]);
float z = float.Parse(elements[2]);
transform.Rotate(x, y, z);
```

Comment: 2 errors: --Assets/GyroNewNewNew.cs(31,47): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `string' expression to type `char[]'-- & --Assets/GyroNewNewNew.cs(31,41): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments--

Comment: Apologies, I used `"` when I should have used `'`, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah I noticed after I posted it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino: Print all three variables with a separator between them, for example like this:

```
Serial.print(Variable1);
Serial.print("|"); //separator
Serial.print(Variable2);
Serial.print("|"); //separator
Serial.println(Variable3); //println instead of print on the last one
```

Unity: use the split function in C# to split the read string into an array:

```
string[] values = variable.Split('|');
```

The variable values should now be an array with three elements that can be parsed into floats.